# Parse a text in an Excel cell and extract date using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string in a merged cell in an excel sheet. I want to extract the date at the end of the string using python. Please help on how we achieve this.

following  is the string which span across cells `A2:L2`

```
(BMC- sales/inventory for (Asia) for week (10-Mar-2019)
```

Comment: You can use python library openpyxl and get the string from the cell.

Comment: What do you need exactly? Extract from excel or parsing the string? Or both?

Comment: Hi Davis, i need to extract the date form the string.

Answer (score 0):

After you extracted the string with python library openpyxl you can further process it with e.g.

```
.split(" ")
```

to split at space.
This results can be put into a list and element [-1] will equal "(10-Mar-2019)".

This can be converted with .strip("(").strip(")") to get 10-Mar-2019